# No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"kindergartens", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm fresh at Rails and I've seem similar problems, but I can't solve mine.

My routes:

```
 resources :kindergartens do
    member do
      put"like",to:"kindergartens#upvote"
    end
    member do
      post :join
      post :quit
    end
```

My model:

```
 acts_as_votable
```

My controller:

```
 def upvote
    @kindergarten = Kindergarten.find(params[:id])
    @kindergarten.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
    end
```

My index.html:

```
  <%= link_to like_kindergarten_path(@kindergarten), method: :put do %>
    <div class="pi-thumbs-up">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" , style="color:#ff5722;"></i>
    <%= kindergarten.get_upvotes.size %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

There is no error in the show.html.erb. But cannot work in the 
index.html.erb.

And I'm getting the same error:

```
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Kindergartens#index
    Showing /Users/liudezheng/Dropbox/未命名文件夹/Lyn-add-
    votes/app/views/kindergartens/index.html.erb where line #66 raised:

    No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"kindergartens", 
    :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: share your index action

Comment: `@kindergarten` is `nil` in your `link_to`

Answer (score 0):

Since it is `index action`, I assume you must be looping `@kindergartens,

so, according to the line **`<%= kindergarten.get_upvotes.size %>`** the parameter of the loop is **`kindergarten`** not **`@kindergarten`**

So, it should be

```
<%= link_to like_kindergarten_path(kindergarten), method: :put do %>
    <div class="pi-thumbs-up">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" , style="color:#ff5722;"></i>
    <%= kindergarten.get_upvotes.size %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**PS:** Share your `index action`, and the complete `index.html` to get the more relavant answers.

Comment: My index action, and the complete index.html is here:[link](http://ldz2017reborn-blog.logdown.com/posts/1840289) Thanks you very much.

Comment: you does not have either `@kindergarten` or `kindergarten` in the controller, but why are you using them in the view? I think that should be code for show page

Comment: You are right .The code for show page is ok.And the problem I just solved that the I putted the html code in the wrong page.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good to hear it is solved. you can accept and vote my answer, if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

`@kindergarten` inside `index.html.erb` is `nil`.
To solve this you probably want to do one of the following:

```
# kindergarten_controller.rb
def index
  @kindergartens = Kindergarten.all
end
```

Your HTML:

```
# kindergartens/index.html.erb
<%= @kindergartens.each do |kindergarten|
<%= link_to like_kindergarten_path(kindergarten), method: :put do %>
  <div class="pi-thumbs-up">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x" , style="color:#ff5722;"></i>
    <%= kindergarten.get_upvotes.size %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This answer looks same as mine.

Comment: Most likely because it's the most common solution to a problem of this kind. Don't worry, I did not copy yours. I just did not refresh the page prior to posting.

Comment: No problem, I was just informing you.

Comment: Ok, that helped.

Cheers!